# Sending Email in rust with Lettre stops working after 3rd email

Tags: rust

I'm currently writing a tool to recursivly watch multiple folders using `notify` and `notify-debouncer-full`.
The filewatching works fine, I've mostly constructed it with example code. The code can most likely be improved but I'm still getting the hang of rust and this is the best I was able to do for now.
The following is the main function with the notify watcher.

Sending the email works for 3 times and then hangs without any error. It detects the 4th file creation and then gets stuck in the `mailer.send(email).await;` function

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {

    let path = "/path/to/watch"
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();
    let mut debouncer = new_debouncer(Duration::from_secs(2), None, tx).unwrap();
    debouncer
        .watcher()
        .watch(std::path::Path::new(path), RecursiveMode::Recursive).unwrap();
    debouncer
        .cache()
        .add_root(std::path::Path::new(path), RecursiveMode::Recursive);

    for result in rx
    {
        match result
        {
            Ok(events) => events.iter().for_each( |event| {
                match event.kind {
                    EventKind::Create(_) =>
                        {
                            if event.paths.first().unwrap().is_file(){
                                let path = format!("{:?}", &event.paths);
                                if path.to_ascii_lowercase().contains(&"subfolder".to_ascii_lowercase())
                                {
                                    println!("{}", &path);
                                    futures::executor::block_on(async { prepare_email(event).await });
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    _ => {}
                }

            }),
            Err(errors) => errors.iter().for_each(|error| println!("{error:?}"))
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a email and send it with SMTP, the email is supposed to contain details about the file upload. I've written the following function to prepare the email:

```rust
async fn prepare_email(event: &DebouncedEvent) {
    let smtp_credentials =
        Credentials::new("smtp_creds".to_string(), "smtp_passwd".to_string());

    let mailer: AsyncSmtpTransport<Tokio1Executor> = AsyncSmtpTransport::<Tokio1Executor>::relay("smtp.server.address").unwrap()
        .credentials(smtp_credentials)
        .build();
    let from = "from";
    let to = "to";
    let subject ="subject";
    let body = "body";
    send_email_smtp(&mailer, from, to, &subject, body).await.unwrap()
}
```

In a previous attempt I've created the mailer in the main and extracted prepare_email to clean up the main function, I've since moved it to prepare_email function in hopes that would help.

Finally the send_mail_smtp function I've prettymuch just copy and pasted from a tutorial

```rust
async fn send_email_smtp(
    mailer: &AsyncSmtpTransport<Tokio1Executor>,
    from: &str,
    to: &str,
    subject: &str,
    body: String,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let email = Message::builder()
        .from(from.parse()?)
        .to(to.parse()?)
        .subject(subject)
        .header(ContentType::TEXT_PLAIN)
        .body(body.to_string())?;
    let x = mailer.send(email).await;
    match x{
        Ok(res) => {println!("OK: {:?}",res.code().detail)}
        Err(res) => {println!("Error: {:?}",res.status().unwrap().detail)}
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I wasn't able to find much in that regards on google and I'm honstely stumped as to what to try next. As I don't get any error and it works for 3 emails without fail, I'm not sure what it could be. It's always the same amount of emails it sends before getting stuck in the function.

Comment: could the service be rate limiting you?

Comment: Hm from my understanding the hoster would return an error stating rate limit exceeded, tho I'll give it a shot with waiting a couple of minutes inbetween uploads, maybe I handle the lettre errors incorrectly, tho I would've thought it would go in the match case to the Error in send_email_smtp, it doesn't even go there after a couple of minutes waiting.

Comment: @DanielA.White I've tested it now with a couple of minutes inbetween each email send, same behaviour after the third mail, time between 3rd and 4th; 5 minutes.  Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Comment: Do you know for sure if any of your `.await`'s are actually returning? The one time I've experienced weird lock ups in rust was when I was testing something on a single core VM and my program needed to run multiple threads, all awaiting things. It would freeze pretty randomly and it all went away when I ran the same code on a 2-core VM.

Comment: @Ragesh the program hangs at the line `let x = mailer.send(email).await;` it does not progress from there and always during the 4th time, after 3 successfull sends. I've tried to set a timeout at the mailer but that did not react either. It never returns from there, even letting it run for 20 minutes roughly. Any ideas what I could try or rewrite to single out a potential issue would be greatly apreciated, I'm at my wits end here.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work around the issue by using `lettre::SmtpTransport::starttls_relay` instead of `AsyncSmtpTransport::<Tokio1Executor>::relay`
Not sure if there was any error in the code as seen in the Original Question but I did not manage to get it to work otherwise.

I've rewritten the code from the question as follows:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    /*code*/

    let smtp_credentials =
        Credentials::new("smtp_user".to_string(), "smtp_password".to_string());

    let mailer = lettre::SmtpTransport::starttls_relay("smtp.example.com").unwrap()
    .credentials(smtp_credentials)
    .authentication(vec![lettre::transport::smtp::authentication::Mechanism::Plain])
    .pool_config(lettre::transport::smtp::PoolConfig::new().max_size(20))
    .build();
    prepare_email(&mailer,event)
}

async fn prepare_email(mailer: &SmtpTransport, event: &DebouncedEvent) {
    let smtp_credentials =
        Credentials::new("smtp_creds".to_string(), "smtp_passwd".to_string());

    let mailer: AsyncSmtpTransport<Tokio1Executor> = AsyncSmtpTransport::<Tokio1Executor>::relay("smtp.server.address").unwrap()
        .credentials(smtp_credentials)
        .build();
    let from = "from";
    let to = "to";
    let subject ="subject";
    let body = "body";
    send_email_smtp(&mailer, from, to, &subject, body).await.unwrap()
}

async fn send_email_smtp(
    mailer: &lettre::SmtpTransport,
    from: &str,
    to: &str,
    subject: &str,
    body: String,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let email = Message::builder()
        .from(from.parse()?)
        .to(to.parse()?)
        .subject(subject)
        .header(ContentType::TEXT_PLAIN)
        .body(body.to_string())?;
    let x = mailer.send(&email);
    match x{
        Ok(res) => {println!("OK: {:?}",res.code().detail)}
        Err(res) => {println!("Error: {:?}",res.status().unwrap().detail)}
    }
    Ok(())
}
```